# "lty" in matlines() is not working when making regression plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I cant get matlines to plot line types properly. I've tried two different formulation methods and every line type code but I keep getting identical plots.

This block of code reproduces the problem with two line types and two formula types. 
Ideally I'd like to have one to have a solid middle line with dashed outer lines, and another that has a long-dashed middle line and dashed outer lines.

Any tips on what I'm missing would be appreciated!

```
x<-iris$Sepal.Length
y<-iris$Sepal.Length
QR<-lm(y ~ x)
QpR<-predict(QR,interval="confidence")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(x, y, type= "n",xaxt="n",yaxt="s")

matlines(x, QpR,lty=1:2,lwd=c(2,2,2))

par(new=FALSE)
plot(x, y, type= "n",xaxt="n",yaxt="n")

matlines(x, QpR,lty=c(1,2,2),lwd=c(2,2,2))

par(new=FALSE)

plot(x, y, type= "n",xaxt="s",yaxt="s")

matlines(x, QpR,lty=c(4,4,4),lwd=c(2,2,2))

par(new=FALSE)

plot(x, y, type= "n",xaxt="s",yaxt="n" )

matlines(x, QpR,lty=1:4,lwd=c(2,2,2))
```

[image]

This one is from my actual code (real data and whatnot) using the same base codes as above. Fit is not perfect in this one. The issue may not be line types, but the way the lines are drawn that causes it to overlap too much... maybe? Either way, something is wrong with the code and I can't see what. Help would be appreciated!!!

[image]

Comment: If you change the Iris columns used to different ones (e.g. x=Petal.Length and y=Sepal.Length) you get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you playing with this model:

```
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
```

It has perfect fit, so confidence intervals have span 0. Check your `QpR`. Its columns are identical so when you call `matlines`, all three lines coincide!

Comment: Bad example I guess. It's not the case in my actual code, that's just a quick reproducible example I worked up. I'll make a different one. Either way though, the line types never change with the current matlines code.